# dojox.gfx.utils.toJson not generating Json in case of clip

Tags: json, dojo

I am trying to generate json of the art `surface.createRect({ x: 100, y: 50, width: 200, height: 100 }).setFill("yellow").setClip({x:100, y:50,width:50,height:50})` using `dojox.gfx.utils.toJson(surface)`. The json generated is as follows:
`[{"shape":{"type":"rect","x":100,"y":50,"width":200,"height":100,"r":0},"fill":{"r":255,"g":255,"b":0,"a":1}}]`
Json has no information of Clip. What mistake am I making or is it the case dojox.gfx.utils.toJson does not support Clip?

Answer (score 0):

Yes unfortunately toJson does not seem to support clipping, it relies on serialize() and it seems clear from the code that clip" is not handled:

https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/gfx/utils.js#L30

This does not seem to be a documented limitation, so feel free to enter a ticket on https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org about it.